# Swift Modal View Controller with transparent background going beyond tab bar

Tags: ios, swift, presentmodalviewcontroller

I tried same code mention in gist : https://gist.github.com/barbietunnie/e5547f35180436ac102cac52a15f8ca3

```
func showModal() {
    let modalViewController = ModalViewController()
    modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext
    presentViewController(modalViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

class ModalViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        view.opaque = false
    }
}
```

Its working fine but in case of tab bar the content is getting beyond tab bar, How can we make content visible upper/front of tab bar?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you are getting ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It worked via `vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen`

Answer (score 2):

I hope it will work for you,

```
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:  "ModalViewController") as! ModalViewController
controller.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
```

Thank You.